# System of 3 equations 3 unknowns grade 2

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

$$1=4a+2b+c$$

$$4=9a+3b+c$$

$$\frac{-b^2+4ac}{4a}=-\frac{b}{2a}+1$$

It's all the afternoon I try to solve this...

Can you point me in the right direction or show me how it's done?

I replaced c with $-4a-2b+1$ in the other two...

First post, sorry for any mistake...

Comment: Back to the original problem: you have a parabola through two given points that does what, additionally?

Comment: "The algebraic way" is not always the most effective way for solving a geometry problem.

Comment: Further hint: the first two equations tell us that a parabola with equation $y(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ goes through $(2,1)$ and $(3,2)$. The third equation tells us that the vertex lies on the line $y=x+1$. The vertex of a parabola of the given form through $(2,1)$ and $(3,2)$ always lies on a hyperbola, hence this problem boils down to intersecting a line and a hyperbola.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

multiplying the third equation by $$4a$$ we obtain:
$$4ac-b^2=-2b+4a$$
solving this equation for $c$ we get
$$c=\frac{b^2-2b+4a}{4a}$$
plugging this in equation (1) and (2):
$$1=4a+2b+\frac{b^2-2b+4a}{4a}$$
$$4=9a+3b+\frac{b^2-2b+4a}{4a}$$
the equation above is equivalent to
$$0=a^2+\frac{1}{2}ab+\frac{b^2-2b}{16}$$
from here we get $$a_{1,2}=-\frac{1}{4}b\pm\sqrt{\frac{b}{8}}$$
this can you set in the last equation to get $b$
we obtain the following Solutions
$$a=-1,b=8,c=11$$
or
$$a=-3,b=18,c=-23$$

Comment: oh i thought this was his calculations, sorry

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Dr. Sonnhard.
I am stuck at "the equation above is equivalent to"... how do you get that? :(

Comment: i have multiplied the equation $$1=4a+2b+\frac{b^2-2b+4a}{4a}$$ by $4a$

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have the following system of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
4\cdot\text{a}+2\cdot\text{b}+\text{c}=1\\
\\
9\cdot\text{a}+3\cdot\text{b}+\text{c}=4\\
\\
\frac{4\cdot\text{a}\cdot\text{c}-\text{b}^2}{4\cdot\text{a}}=1-\frac{\text{b}}{2\cdot\text{a}}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

Using the first and the third equation:

$$\frac{\left(1-2\cdot\text{b}-\text{c}\right)\cdot\text{c}-\text{b}^2}{1-2\cdot\text{b}-\text{c}}=1-\frac{2\cdot\text{b}}{1-2\cdot\text{b}-\text{c}}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{c}=1-\text{b}\pm\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{\text{b}}\tag2$$

Where $\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{\text{b}}\ne\text{b}$

Now, using the first and the second equation we can write:

$$1-4\cdot\text{a}-2\cdot\text{b}=4-9\cdot\text{a}-3\cdot\text{b}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{b}=3-5\cdot\text{a}\tag3$$

So, for the first equation we get:

$$4\cdot\text{a}+2\cdot\left(3-5\cdot\text{a}\right)+\left(1-\left(3-5\cdot\text{a}\right)\pm\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{3-5\cdot\text{a}}\right)=1\tag4$$

And from equation $(4)$ you can find that we get the following two solutions for $\text{a}$: $\text{a}=-3,\text{a}=-1$

Answer (score 1):

This make lay out makes me think of polynomials of degree 2.

$p(x) = ax^2 + bx +c\\
p(1) = 1\\
p(2) = 4\\
$

It would be really nice if $p(x) = (x-1)^2$ unfortunately it doesn't fit with the last equation

$9a + 3b + c = 4\\
4a + 2b + c = 1\\
5a + b = 3\\
b = 3-5a$

substitute

$4a  + 2(3-5a) + c = 1\\
c = 6a - 5$

And now we can attack the 3rd equation entirely in terms of a

$\frac {-(3-5a)^2 + 4a(6a-5)}{4a} = \frac {-(3-5a)}{2a} + 1\\
-(3-5a)^2 + 4a(6a-5) = -2(3-5a) + 4a\\
-9 + 30 a - 25a^2 + 24a^2 - 20a = -6 + 14a\\
a^2 + 4a + 3 = 0\\
(a+3)(a+1) = 0$

$a = -1, b = 8, c = -11\\
a = -3, b = 18, c = -23$